# Does ccall really convert arguments passed by pointer?

Tags: arrays, pointers, julia, implicit-conversion, ffi

Considering a dynamic library with this native function that returns the sum of all even (32-bit unsigned) numbers in an array:

```c
uint32_t sum_of_even(const uint32_t *numbers, size_t length);
```

The implementation of the function above was written in Rust as below, and packaged into a C dynamic library.

```rust
use libc::size_t;
use std::slice;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn sum_of_even(n: *const u32, len: size_t) -> u32 {
    let numbers = unsafe {
        assert!(!n.is_null());
        slice::from_raw_parts(n, len as usize)
    };

    numbers
        .iter()
        .filter(|&v| v % 2 == 0)
        .sum()
}
```

I wrote the following Julia (v1.0.1) wrapper function:

```
lib = Libdl.dlopen(libname)
sumofeven_sym = Libdl.dlsym(lib, :sum_of_even)

sumofeven(a) = ccall(
    sumofeven_sym,
    UInt32,
    (Ptr{UInt32}, Csize_t),
    a, length(a)
)
```

The documentation states multiple times that arguments in [`ccall`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#ccall) are converted to become compatible with the C function prototype (emphasis mine):

> Each `argvalue` to the `ccall` will be converted to the corresponding `argtype`, by automatic insertion of calls to `unsafe_convert(argtype, cconvert(argtype, argvalue))`. (See also the documentation for [`unsafe_convert`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.unsafe_convert) and [`cconvert`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.cconvert) for further details.) In most cases, **this simply results in a call to `convert(argtype, argvalue)`**.

And moreover, that when passing an `Array{T}` by `Ptr{U}` to a C function, the call is invalidated if the two types T and U are different, since no reinterpret cast is added (section [Bits Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#man-bits-types-1)):

> When an array is passed to C as a `Ptr{T}` argument, it is not reinterpret-cast: **Julia requires that the element type of the array matches `T`**, and the address of the first element is passed.
>
> Therefore, if an `Array` contains data in the wrong format, **it will have to be explicitly converted** using a call such as `trunc(Int32, a)`.

However, this is seemingly not the case. If I deliberately pass an array with another type element:

```
println(sumofeven(Float32[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

The program calls the C function with the array passed directly, without converting the values nor complaining about the different element types, resulting in either senseless output or a segmentation fault.

If I redefine the function to accept a `Ref{UInt32}` instead of a `Ptr{UInt32}`, I am prevented from calling it with the array of floats:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float32,1} to an object of type UInt32
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T<:Number}, !Matched::T<:Number) where T<:Number at number.jl:6
  convert(::Type{T<:Number}, !Matched::Number) where T<:Number at number.jl:7
  convert(::Type{T<:Integer}, !Matched::Ptr) where T<:Integer at pointer.jl:23
  ...
```

However, `Ref` was not designed for arrays.

Making the example work with `Ptr{UInt32}` requires me to either specify `Array{UInt32}` as the type of input `a` (static enforcement), or `convert` the array first for a more flexible function.

```
sumofeven(a:: Array{UInt32}) = ccall( # ← either this
    sumofeven_sym,
    UInt32,
    (Ptr{UInt32}, Csize_t),
    convert(Array{UInt32}, a), # ← or this
    length(a))
```

With that, I still feel that there is a gap in my reasoning. What is the documentation really suggesting when it says that an array passed to C as a `Ptr{T}` is not reinterpret-cast? Why is Julia letting me pass an array of different element types without any explicit conversion?

Comment: I'm don't really know anything about the FFI, but [this part](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#When-to-use-T,-Ptr{T}-and-Ref{T}-1) of the docs seems to suggest that you should use `Ref` instead of `Ptr`, since the input array is supposed to be managed by Julia.

Comment: @phg Indeed, `Ptr` and `Ref` happen to make conversions behave differently. I have edited the question to include that detail.

Comment: Type-checking part aside, the undefined error might be caused by that you are not creating a variable and passing it to `ccall`, you are directly passing an expression which might create an error due to GC issues (this is just a guess). 
I think there used to be a [warning](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7694) when type of array and `T` did not match. `unsafe_convert(::Type{Ptr{S}}, a::AbstractArray{T}) where {S,T} = convert(Ptr{S}, unsafe_convert(Ptr{T}, a))` in `pointer.jl` handles when the types differ which *I think* in turn *reinterprets* the pointer calling `bitcast`.

Comment: I believe this behavior should be reported as an issue.

Comment: @hckr That is insightful, but yet intriguing. Shouldn't the parameter function `a` behave like a variable in this context? As the native function does not even retain the pointer to the array, I would say that the array still lives for as long as it has to. Doing `ccall(sumofeven_sym, UInt32, (Ptr{UInt32}, Csize_t), UInt32[1,2,3], 3)` also seems to work fine in practice, although this doesn't prove much: UB does work in mysterious ways. Nevertheless, I will seek to report this upstream then!

Comment: Filed issue [julia#29850](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29850).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This turned out to be either a bug in the core library or a very misguided documentation, depending on the perspective ([issue #29850](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29850)). The behavior of the function `unsafe_convert` changed from version 0.4 to 0.5, in a way that makes it more flexible than what is currently suggested.

According to this [commit](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/f6f616ce50e40b4337feb79a8bad20519ff75e86#diff-d646a6707a27b7ba7c211a5fa6347321), `unsafe_convert` changed from this:

```
unsafe_convert(::Type{Ptr{Void}}, a::Array) = ccall(:jl_array_ptr, Ptr{Void}, (Any,), a)
```

To this:

```
unsafe_convert{S,T}(::Type{Ptr{S}}, a::AbstractArray{T}) = convert(Ptr{S}, unsafe_convert(Ptr{T}, a))
```

For arrays, this relaxed implementation will enable a transformation from an array of `T` to a pointer of another type `S`. In practice, `unsafe_convert(cconvert(array))` will reinterpret-cast the array's base pointer, as in the C++ nomenclature. We are left with a dangerously reinterpreted array across the FFI boundary.

The key takeaway is that one needs to take extra care when passing arrays to C functions, as the element type of an array in a C-call function parameter is not statically enforced. Use type signatures and/or explicit conversions where applicable.